# stored procedure vs. function in postgresql and which is better for executing dml statements

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3

I'm using postgresql 9.3. If I want to add the following steps and call these steps as a routine, would it be better to use a function or stored procedure?

My basic steps are:

```
RENAME TABLE FOOBAR_1234.table1_org TO FOOBAR_1234.table1_old;
DELETE FOOBAR_1234.table1_old WHERE 1=1;
RENAME TABLE FOOBAR_1234.table1 TO FOOBAR_1234.table1_org;
```

What I also need is the flexibility to parameterize the ID as in `1234` with any ID, example `5678`.

If you have an example, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as a stored procedure in PostgreSQL. All PostgreSQL has are SQL-callable functions defined in a number of languages - `LANGUAGE sql`, `LANGUAGE plpgsql`, `LANGUAGE plperl`, etc.

Additionally, there's no `RENAME TABLE` command. You want `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO ...`.

This particular example must be written in PL/PgSQL using `EXECUTE` because it relies on dynamic SQL. See the numerous existing examples on Stack Overflow of using PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE`. Something like a PL/PgSQL function with:

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I RENAME TO %I.%I;',
    'FOOBAR_'||_schema_id, 'table1_org',
    'FOOBAR_'||_schema_id, 'table1_old');
```

Edit: OK, more complete example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(_schema_id integer)
RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I RENAME TO %I.%I;',
        'FOOBAR_'||_schema_id, 'table1_org',
        'FOOBAR_'||_schema_id, 'table1_old');

    -- Now TRUNCATE the table and do your second `RENAME`
    -- in subsequent EXECUTE statements.
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Additionally, the command `DELETE FOOBAR_1234.table1_old WHERE 1=1;` to me looks like you are actually trying to `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: Postgres has stored procedures since v11 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html